# Account with most Won opportunities

Tags: roll-up-summary

I am trying to find the Account with most Opportunities in Closed/Won state.
Is there any way to achieve this functionality using configuration, without code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to use up a custom field on the Opportunity, in order to achieve this.

You can filter the Account roll up summary field to only Count (not Sum) Opportunities where `Won EQUALS True`.

See this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm) for more details.

Comment: Of course, much simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Formula field on the Opportunity as follows:

```
IF(TEXT(StageName) == 'Closed Won', 1, 0)
```

Which would yield 1 if the opp is Closed/Won.

Then, on your Account, create a Rollup Summary that SUMs these. Then, essentially what you'd have is a count of the Closed/Won opps on an Account, which you could then produce a report or list view for.